# How to fix Error on expected semicolon in c++?

Tags: c++

Can Someone help me to fix this error? It always returns the error (as mentioned in the question). I am beginner in c++ and any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance

EDIT:

THIS IS THE INCLUDES

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>


 std::istringstream rows(input);
 std::vector<row> data{std::istream_iterator<row>(rows),std::istream_iterator<row>()}; //the error occurs on this line
 std::cout << table(data);
```

EDIT2:

Code for struct table

```
struct table {
    table(std::vector<row> const &r) :t(r) { }
    std::vector<row> const &t;

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, table const &t) {
        os << "<table>";
        std::copy(t.t.begin(), t.t.end(), std::ostream_iterator<row>(os));
        return os << "</table>";
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you also add the complete definition for your `row` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should not be an initializer list, see if changing to `()` helps.

```
std::vector<row> data(std::istream_iterator<row>(rows),std::istream_iterator<row>());
```

Now you are calling the constructor which takes a pair of iterators.

Comment: Hi Sir, but the code belows return this error  `4 IntelliSense: no instance of constructor "table::table" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (std::vector<row, std::allocator<row>> (std::istream_iterator<row, char, std::char_traits<char>, ptrdiff_t> rows, std::istream_iterator<row, char, std::char_traits<char>, ptrdiff_t> (*)())) c:\Users\SDG11\Desktop\mp\lastnatalaga\machine_prob\machine_prob\machine_prob.cpp 495 16 machine_prob`

Comment: For the time being, can you change the code to be just `std::vector<row> data;` and see what happens? I can't see any reason why the constructor would fail to bind for `table` otherwise.

Comment: It runs sir, But there is no output

Comment: There won't be, because now your `data` object is completely empty. Let me think what the error is in that.

Comment: Ok Sir. Thank you for helping me  with this.

Comment: Please take a look at this [minimal program](https://godbolt.org/z/8ZbmUR). It seems to compile just fine for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209351/discussion-between-tanveer-badar-and-alexis-abulencia-villar).

Comment: Ok Sir. I have seen this code also in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255935/parsing-file-in-c-and-writing-it-into-html-in-table. This if for creating an html table with c++. I would like to implement this code for my project. Actually, this is the exact code the error exist.

Comment: Hi Sir. Thank you for helping me out. I already figured it out with you solution, I only have to do like this `std::vector<row> data((std::istream_iterator<row>(rows)),std::istream_iterator<row>());`. Thank you Sir. God Bless!